# yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context@react-native-community/masked-view

Tags: ios, git, react-native

I am running the below command and getting the error Command failed.
Exit code: 128 .... I have generated SSHKey and copied it to my Github profile....

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context@react-native-community/masked-view
yarn add v1.22.10
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/react-native-community/masked-view.git
Directory: /Users/admin/Desktop/NBNB
Output:
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering https://github.com/react-native-community/masked-view.git is not accessible, it must be:

- a non-existent repository (hence your error message)
- or a private repository, in which case double-check if your GitHub user account is indeed a member of the `react-native-community` organisation.

Check also if ssh -Tv git@github.com does end up with a "Welcome" message including the expected GitHub user account.